# Wrapping a Python function using NumPy arrays in C++

Tags: c++, python-3.x, numpy, cython, python-embedding

I have a bunch of functions written in python (for rapid prototyping). My main project is in C++ and I wanna call these functions from my C++ program.

These functions use some specialized python modules like numpy, pyside etc.

I tried using the "--embed" functionality of Cython to convert these functions to a C file and then compile that to an object file. Only problem is, Cython converts these functions into standalone programs, ie. makes a main() function in the .c files it creates. I don't want that, I just wanna be able to call them from my C++ program and use the results I obtain.

Are there any other alternatives, I could use to achieve this (Python/C API, SWIG etc)? Or am I using cython to embed python wrong?

I am using Python3 and Cython 0.22.1.

Comment: I think you will have to use [Python/C API](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/)  for this.

Comment: Doesn't that entail a lot of confusing reference decrement calls? I read that also involves a lot of data type conversion from Python to C. How will I convert numpy arrays to a type compatible in C++?

Also, is there any other examples/documentation on this area apart from [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/embedding.html)?

Comment: As far as I understand the `--embed` cython flag [embeds the python interpreter](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/EmbeddingCython) it does not allow you to interface Python code from C.   For acessing numpy arrays, use the [Numpy C-API](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.html).  Well yes, using Python code from C is generally more work than the other way around.